# Swift trailing closure can't compile

Tags: swift

I tried to turn a sequence of key-value pairs (tuples) into a dictionary:

```
let pairs = [("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("a", 3), ("b", 4)]

let firstValues = Dictionary( pairs,
    uniquingKeysWith: { (first, _) in first }
)
// ["b": 2, "a": 1]
```

but when I try to use the trailing closure syntax, the code just can't compile, why?

```
// ⛔️ error: contextual closure type '(_, _) -> _' 
//    expects 2 arguments, but 1 was used in closure body
let firstValues2 = Dictionary( pairs ) { $0 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing to do with the trailing closure syntax.

If you try the code below it will complain as well:

```
let firstValues = Dictionary(pairs, uniquingKeysWith: { $0 })
```

The compiler is complaining that you are not using the new value. You have a few ways to go around.

1) give the values a name:

```
let firstValues1 = Dictionary(pairs) { oldValue, newValue in oldValue }
```

2) you can also ignore the value using an underscore

```
let firstValues2 = Dictionary(pairs) { oldValue, _ in oldValue }
```

3) make any type of use of the old value as well as the new value. A simple print would suffice the compiler.

```
let firstValues3 = Dictionary(pairs) {
    print($1)
    return $0
}
```